# Create a log of Fragments visited

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an app that goes to 3 different fragments on button clicks i.e. MainActivity --> (MainActivity)button press --> Fragment 1 --> (Fragment 1)button press --> Fragment 2 etc. I am trying to create a log of the fragments visited that can be stored even if the application is closed. So if all fragments were visited then the log would show: "Fragment 1, Fragment 2, Fragment 3"

In short my question would be how can I remember data from each fragment to create a log and how can I keep this log in the memory of the app even if the app is killed. The main activity is shown below along with one of the fragments (all of them are the same right now)

MAIN ACTIVITY:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button start_button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //get button references
    start_button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.new_home);


    start_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            loadFragment(new FirstFragment());
            start_button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
}

public void loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    //create fragment manager
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    //create a fragment transaction to begin the transaction and replace the fragment
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    //replace the frame layout with new fragment
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();//save the changes
}
```

}

FRAGMENT:

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {

View view;
Button firstButton;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //inflate the layout for the fragment
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first,container,false);

    firstButton = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.firstButton);

    firstButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Activity Logged",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          ///////////LOG FRAGMENT HERE////////////////////////////////
        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).loadFragment(new Fragment2());

        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

}

Comment: You can write into file (Text file) on fragment onCreate

Comment: @androidXP how do you write to a file ?

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this method to write into text file (By default this method write into Default download folder).Params are 1.Data you want to write 2. Directory you want to store in 3. Filename with extension (.txt for text file)

put this method in parent activity

```
public void writeToFile(String data,String Dir,String FileName) {

        try {

            File dir=new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)+"/"+Dir);
            Log.d(TAG,"Dir "+dir);
            if (dir.exists() == false) {
                dir.mkdirs();
            }
            final File file = new File(dir, FileName);
            Log.d(TAG,"File Path "+file);
            FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file,true);
            OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
            myOutWriter.append(data);
            myOutWriter.flush();
            myOutWriter.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```

and call like this from your Fragments:

```
((MainActivity)getActivity()).writeToFile("Fragment1","MyLog","TrackLog.txt");
```

Comment: how do I access the file? will it be stored on the phone?

Comment: You can see it in your download folder. You can access it via any file explorer app like Astro, File commander etc.. If you Add dir parameter in method then it will create mentioned folder inside default download folder of your phone.

Comment: my logcat shows this as the output and I cannot find the file anywhere on the phone? Is there something I am missing?                
D/TAG: Dir /storage/emulated/0/Download/MyLog
D/TAG: File Path /storage/emulated/0/Download/MyLog/TrackLog.txt

Comment: file Path /storage/emulated/0/Download/MyLog/TrackLog.txt.
download astro file manager --> open app-->click internal storage --> locate Download folder --> MyLog --> here you will find your file

Comment: the problem is that my Download folder is empty when i check it, with not even the folder called MyLog inside it. Is there a reason it wouldnt show up?

Comment: You can check your log its showing its there so u need look for it again

Comment: I forgot to add <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> to the manifest, i have edited your answer to include that